# Is this a good way to be root in a makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

Is this a good way to be root in a makefile?

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
INSTDIR = /usr/bin/
OBJS = main.o file.o gen.o stat.o

program1: $(OBJS)
        gcc -o program1 $(OBJS)

main.o: main.c file.h  gen.h stat.h
        gcc -c main.c

file.o: file.c file.h
        gcc -c file.c

gen.o: gen.c gen.h
        gcc -c gen.c

stat.o: stat.c stat.h
        gcc -c stat.c

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJS) program1

install:
        @if [ -f program1 ]; then \
                if [ $$(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then \
                        cp program1 $(INSTDIR) && \
                        echo "Installed in $(INSTDIR)" ; \
                else \
                        (sudo cp program1 $(INSTDIR) 2> /dev/null && \
                        echo "Installed in $(INSTDIR)") || \
                        (echo 'No sudo on this machine, trying su.' \
                        && su -c "cp program1 $(INSTDIR)" && \
                        echo "Installed in $(INSTDIR)") ; \
                fi ; \
        else \
                echo "There was no program to install, run make." ; \
        fi

uninstall:
        @if [ -f $(INSTDIR)program1 ]; then \
                if [ $$(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then \
                        rm $(INSTDIR)program1 && \
                        echo "Uninstalled in $(INSTDIR)" ; \
                else \
                        (sudo rm $(INSTDIR)program1 2> /dev/null && \
                        echo "Uninstalled in $(INSTDIR)") || \
                        (echo 'No sudo on this machine, trying su.' \
                        && su -c "rm $(INSTDIR)program1" && \
                        echo "Uninstalled in $(INSTDIR)") ; \
                fi ; \
        else \
                echo "There was no program to remove." ; \
        fi
```

Comment: If you insist on writing your own rules, please use DESTDIR instead of INSTDIR, as it is more standard.

Answer (score 20):

## NO!

First, generally users do `sudo make install`. Second, you didn't think about cases when the program is installed into a custom directory, which doesn't always need root privileges. Packaging tools use this feature, for example, and they don't have root privileges.

Comment: Not it "doesn't need root priveleges", it is *harmful* if the installer has them.  The usual user then may not be able to edit and/or to access the files installed.